# How to perform an async Cassandra lookup using Flink asynchronous I/O inside a ProcessFunction?

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink

I want to perform a Cassandra look up using [Flink asynchronous I/O](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/asyncio.html) inside a ProcessFunction. Now this works fine when I do it in the main method where the result in returned as a DataStream, like so -

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ConnectionProps props = new ConnectionProps(args, "props.properties");

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    Tuple2<String, String> sample1 = new Tuple2<>("flink", "flink-user-1");
    Tuple2<String, String> sample2 = new Tuple2<>("flink", "flink-user-2");

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> samples = env.fromElements(sample1, sample2);

    //Result will be in the form of <query, resultset.toString()>
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> lookupResult = AsyncDataStream
                .orderedWait(samples, new AsyncCassandraReader(props), 
                             5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
                             props.getAsyncIoCapacity());

    lookupResult.print();
}
```

Where the `AsyncCassandraReader` has an `asyncInvoke` method that does a Cassandra lookup based on the `DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>>` passed.

How do I do the same thing from inside of a `ProcessFunction`?